# Value not incremented

Tags: java

Why increment salary is showing output as 0.0 instead of adding value?

```
class Dcoder
{ 

    static double salary;

    static double increment;
    public static double calSal()
    {
        salary=30000.00;
        return salary;  
    }
    public static double incSal()
    {
        double salary=30000.00;
        double salary2=5000.00;
        double increment=salary+salary2;
        return increment;
    }
    public static void displaySal()
    {
        String employee="Narrigaadu";
        System.out.println("Salary of "+employee+" is "+salary);
        System.out.println("Increased salary is "+increment);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        calSal();
        incSal();
        displaySal();   
    }      
}
```

Comment: Even I removed double salary=30000.00, it is showing same output as 0.0

Comment: Output:Salary of Narrigaadu is 30000.0
Increased salary is 0.0

Comment: Because you assign `increment` not `salary`  : `double increment=salary+salary2;`

Comment: `double salary` and `double increment`  in `incSal()` will hide/shadow the fields `salary` and `increment` that are defined on class level. Besides that, you're returning `increment` but are not using that value. Thus the return type in that method is superfluous and could as well be `void`.

Comment: This is where stepping through the code in your debugger should be the fastest way to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is two-fold:

1. When you wrote `double salary=30000.00;`, you created a new, local variable. This isn't the main problem here, but it would cause you to get incorrect results later, and would cause conflicts with other fixes.
2. You never actually change `salary`. You calculate the new number, store it in `increment`, then return `increment`. Returning doesn't update the variable though.

You simply need to update the `salary` variable:

```
public static void incSal()
{
    double salary2 = 5000.00;
    double increment = salary + salary2;

    salary = increment; // Here
}
```

It can also be made more succinct by getting rid of `increment`:

```
public static void incSal()
{
    double salary2 = 5000.00;

    salary = salary + salary2
    // salary += salary2; // Or, more succinctly
}
```

I also changed the return type to `void` as this is a effectful function; not one that I would expect to return something. This isn't best practice, but it makes the most sense given how you have the rest of the class set up.

---

As a side note, using `static` everything isn't really appropriate in this case. I recommend looking up what `static` is used for, as it's a more niche use case than what you're using it for here.

Comment: @markspace I mentioned that at the end. I figured being explicit and verbose would be more helpful here. I can make an addition though.

Comment: I think it's fine to be verbose, but that type of assignment is so common I think it should be spelled out as well.

Comment: And I just noticed the OP's whole class including fields are all `static`.  Jeeze.  (@Carcegenicate That's for adding that, I think it's far more informational for new programmers.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,

```
  class Dcoder
{ 

    static double salary;

    static double increment;
    public static double calSal()
    {
        salary=30000.00;
        return salary;  
    }
    public static double incSal()
    {
        double salary=30000.00;
        double salary2=5000.00;
        increment=salary+salary2;
        return increment;
    }
    public static void displaySal()
    {
        String employee="Narrigaadu";
        System.out.println("Salary of "+employee+" is "+salary);
        System.out.println("Increased salary is "+increment);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        calSal();
        incSal();
        displaySal();   
    }      
}
```